# ESP32 PCB Layout Review

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, esp32, iot

I am designing this PCB, which consists of an ESP32, with its respective 3.3v (AP2112K-3.3 Switch regulator) and 5v power supply (AP62150 Switch regulator), an RTC clock, an RS485 converter for the moisture sensors and a 5v relay with the optocoupler for the solenoid valve.

I need to know your opinions before I send to manufacture the boards. Is there anything I should change? Is there any value that is not right?

[image: schematic]

Comment: @tobalt I have added the full res version, let me know :)

Comment: There is still no layout.. Otherwise, the schematic is well drawn, so should be easy to check for others.

Comment: It works in my devices... Check your browsers.

Comment: We see a schematic, but no PCB layout.

Comment: Your choice and values of capacitors seems random. Eg C1,2,3,13. Your RS485 protection may be inadequate as you can expect 12V on your bus. U5 is superfluous. No input protection against reverse or overvoltage. The actual specification of a number of the capacitors is critical, so even though your schematic may be ‘correct’ the pcb may not perform as expected. As well,the pcb layout is also critical as it forms part of your circuit.

Comment: While +5 is ready and +3.3 lags behind, a current through R7, the LED in the coupler and LED1 into the RELAY-1 output protection diode is possible. Put a resistor of 100 ohm in series with SW1 to avoid contact erosion from high discharge currents.